# Deleting a DataFrame from a list of DataFrames depending on the DataFrame - python?

Tags: python, dataframe

I has a list of DataFrames and I want to delete DataFrames from the list which fulfill any of the below conditions:

- If the DataFrame has 2 or less columns.
- If the DataFrame contains the string 'A3' anywhere.

The code I have tried for the column length is shown below here the list is named df_list:

```
for i in df_list:
   if len(i.columns) == 1:
      del[i]
```

or

```
df_list = [i for i in df_list if not (i.shape[1] == 2)]
```

The code I have tried to remove DataFrames that include the string 'A3' anywhere is:

```
df_list = [i for i in df_list if not ('A3' in i.columns)]
```

I know my numbers are wrong but neither are removing anything from my list when they should, does anyone know the way to correctly do this?

Comment: When you say "contains", do you mean in the *columns* or in the *data*?

Comment: Absolutely anywhere in the DataFrame.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.bls.gov/web/empsit/cesbmart.htm'
df_list = pd.read_html(url)


key_word = 'CES'

delete_by_idx = []
for idx, dataframe in enumerate(df_list):
    A3_found = False

    # Check if A3 is in any row
    for i, row in dataframe.iterrows():
        if row.str.contains(key_word).any():
           A3_found = True

    # If A3 was found, delete the dataframe
    if A3_found == True:
        delete_by_idx.append(idx)  
        continue

    # If A3 is in the columns, delete the dataframe
    cols =  [ str(col_name) for col_name in list(dataframe.columns) ]
    if any(key_word in x for x in cols):
        delete_by_idx.append(idx) 
        continue

    # If columns less than or equal to 2, delete the dataframe
    if len(dataframe.columns) <= 2:
        delete_by_idx.append(idx) 
        continue

delete_by_idx.sort(reverse=True)
for each in delete_by_idx:        
    del df_list[each]
```

Comment: I've just run this and its nor removing anything from my list ?? the majority of my dataframes contain strings could this possibly be the issue?

Comment: try it again, I found a typo

Comment: @Rose, sorry about that. I just realized deleting by index won't work unless you go in descending order. I had it going ascending.  This should now work

Comment: I've just run the new code you suggested however on the row  "if any('A3' in x for x in list(dataframe.columns)):" I am receiving the error "argument of type 'int' is not iterable" ?

Comment: @Rose I made the adjustment. If it still throws the error, is it possible to share a short list of the dataframes? Or at least the one dataframe it gets stuck on? Would just make it easier to test if I have the data you are using to test it against.

Answer (score 0):

This will check for "A3" in the column names. You can then use the same format to check the values of the columns.

```
for each in df_list:
    if 'A3' in each.loc[0]:
        df_list.remove(each)
```